# pFlutter deep links not working from browser

Tags: flutter, dart, deep-linking

I am trying to create a deep link to a specific page in my flutter app's AndroidManifest.xml. please help is required. Here is my android manifest

```
   <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true"
                tools:targetApi="m">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:host="ingrid.io"/>
                <data android:path="/deeplink/"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:host="ingrid.io"/>
                <data android:path="/deeplink/"/>
                <!-- Add more data elements for other paths -->
            </intent-filter>
```

I already granted deeplinking to my app package name using ingrid.io but I am confused. The link is not going through no matter what I do
and here is the code i am using to listen to the link.

```
Future<void> initUniLinks() async {
    try {
      final initialLink = await getInitialLink();
      _handleLink(Uri.parse(initialLink!));
    } on PlatformException {
    }
    uriLinkStream.listen((Uri? uri) {
      _handleLink(uri);
    }, onError: (err) {
     
    });
  }
  void _handleLink(Uri? link) {
    if (link != null) {
      if (link.path == '/account-result') {
       Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
         return AccountResult();
       }));
      }
    }
  }
```